# Intersect lists on KeyValuePair key?

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

How do I insertsect two lists of KeyValuePairs based on their keys? I have tried:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> listA = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> listB = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
...
var result = listA.Intersect(listB);
```

Which expectedly doesn't work. Do I need to write my own comparer based on the key or is there a easy way using LINQ/Lambda?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var keysFromB = new HashSet<string>(listB.Select(x => x.Key));
var result = listA.Where(x => keysFromB.Remove(x.Key));
```

Note that this code mimics the behaviour  of [`Intersect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx) by using the [`Remove`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342694.aspx) method. This means that both sequences are treated as sets: if there are multiple items with the same key in `listA` then `result` will only contain one of those items. If you don't want this behaviour then use the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356440.aspx) method instead of `Remove`.

Answer (score 5):

I *suspect* you would indeed have to write your own comparer - at least to use `Intersect`.

You could use ProjectionEqualityComparer from [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) to make this easy though:

```
// Ick what a mouthful
var comparer = ProjectionEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string, string>>.Create
       (x => x.Key);

var result = listA.Intersect(listB, comparer);
```

If the keys are unique within each list, another option would be a join:

```
var commonPairs = from pairA in listA
                  join pairB in listB on pairA.Key equals pairB.Key
                  select new { pairA, pairB };
```

Comment: It's close to what I need, but I can't be sure the keys will be unique. (And I would rather not reference another assembly.)

Comment: @Alex: The link was broken very briefly, but I fixed it afterwards. It should be fine.