# Intersecting number of keyValuePair Lists according to the Key element

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have  number of lists of type:

```
public List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, 
                  List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>> rawComparisonObject;
```

I want to get the intersection of these lists according to the "key" of the KeyValuePair that constructs the List

I tried:
`List2 = list1.Intersect(list2).Intersect(list3)......` etc , but as you can see it Intersects all the KeyValuePair variable, not the one I want.

I also tried 
[Intersect lists on KeyValuePair key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701878/intersect-lists-on-keyvaluepair-key)

In the following form:

```
    public List<List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>>> getCommon(List<ResourceInformation> input)
    {
        List<List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>>> rawComparisonObject =
            new List<List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string,string>,List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>>>();
        foreach (ResourceInformation item in input)
        {
            rawComparisonObject.Add(item.rawComparisonObject);                
        }

        foreach (List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>> item in rawComparisonObject)
        {

        }
        List<List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>>> common =
            new List<List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < (rawComparisonObject.Count-1); i++)
        {
            var keysFromB = new HashSet<KeyValuePair<string, string>>(rawComparisonObject[i].Select(x => x.Key));
            var result = rawComparisonObject[i+1].Where(x => keysFromB.Remove(x.Key));
            common.Add(result.ToList());
        }
        return common;

    }
```

it returned very faulty values, 
is there 
Any easy way to do this ?

---

I use this data structure in linked data work, to get common objects as a result of comparing between objects

Ex: Batman vs. Inception

**should return:**

Type : Movie | Movie

Starring : Christian Bale | Leonardo Dicaprio

of course everything is highlighted with it's URI link, that's why I need keyValuePair one for URI and other for label....

I tried my best to explain this complex data-structure. hope it's clear enough

Comment: Your data-structure is a little complex.  Maybe you can give an example of what is stored in there and what example output you need?

Comment: I think you should design your datamodel in some better way...

Answer (score 3):

As I understand the code you've written, here's my (revised) translation:

```
public List<List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>>> getCommon(List<ResourceInformation> input)
{
    var rawComparisonObject = 
        input.Select(item => item.rawComparisonObject).ToList();

    var common = rawComparisonObject.Zip(
        rawComparisonObject.Skip(1), 
        (prevItems, nextItems) => 
            (from next in nextItems
            join prev in prevItems on next.Key equals prev.Key
            select next).ToList()).ToList();

    return common;
}
```

Edit: the above translation, omits the empty foreach loop in the middle and uses the join as a filter, projecting only the 'next' elements that pass the join criteria. I tend to favor join for this kind of filtering as I know it utilizes hashing under the covers to efficiently perform the matching it does.

The problem with my prior version was that it collected the join results using a 'group join' variable which led to that extra enumerable that we didn't want. After the change, the inner `ToList()` is analogous to the `result` variable in the original code sample provided in the post. The outer `ToList()` is the final `common` variable's (re)packaging of the results. I believe this will provide results similar to that of the original code; however, I strongly encourage testing to verify that the results meet expectations.

IMHO, the right thing to do would be to refactor to simplify the generics use until we can reason about them better. In a brief interim attempt I changed `GetCommon` to a generic type like this (later changing it back):

```
public List<List<KeyValuePair<T, List<T>>>> GetCommon<T>(/*List<ResourceInformation> input*/)
```

From there, we could promote the `rawComparisonObject` list to a parameter of the method - and in the process of doing so, we would replace the current parameter of the method. The use of `var` typing allows us to avoid changing the type for the `common` local variable (so long as we're careful that the output type matches the expected return type, which was my bad on the original translation.)

There are many more design ideas and questions than I could comfortably examine here, so I am going to close without attempting to do so. I do want to offer that this was a good challenge - sometimes LINQ isn't the right choice, but even when it isn't the right choice, a change of approach can make it worth trying. Thanks!

Comment: I think we're going somewhere with this, but 'common' returns List<IEnumerable<List<<KeyValuePair<string,string>,List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>>>>> 
I think you misplaces a .ToList() somewhere, cause my return type is just

List<List<KeyValuePair<KeyValuePair<string, string>, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>>>   no IEnumerable there..

Comment: Posting some sample data and code to make the movie example concrete would help. Also helpful is providing the expected output in a structured form.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with linq, although likely you should change your data model to be more efficient:

```
var keys = list1.select( kv => kv.Key).intersection(list2.select(kv => kv.Key)
var result = list1.where( key => keys.contains(key).TolLst()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to intersect the KeyValuePairs on their key you should implement a custom [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and use [`Intersect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method like this:

```
class KeyValyePairComparer : IEqualityComparer<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    public bool Equals(KeyValuePair<string, string> x, KeyValuePair<string, string> y)
    {
        return x.Key == y.Key;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<string, string> item)
    {
        return item.Key.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Using the implementation above you can get the intersection with the query:

```
var comparer = new KeyValuePairComparer();
var intersection = list1.Intersect(list2, comparer).Intersect(list3, comparer);
```